# How do you swap the commands for two symbols?

Tags: symbols

I find that I much prefer `\varphi` to `\phi` and generally would rather use the `\varphi` than the `\phi`. But it's three more characters to type `\varphi` instead of `\phi`, which is most troublesome. So I would like to swap the two commands. I tried a couple of things on my own, but one resulted in an infinite loop in compilation and the other led to `\varphi` taking over all of the `\phi` commands I made. What would be the correct way to do this?

Comment: `\let\phi\varphi`

Comment: @Gonzalo This defines '\phi' to be '\varphi', but doesn't define '\varphi' to be the "old" '\phi'.

Comment: The idea is the same: `\let\oldphi\phi
\let\phi\varphi
\let\varphi\oldphi`

Comment: I usually say to go with `\let\phi\varphi`, as the two symbols very rarely are used together in the same document (a polite way to say: "never use both in the same document").

Comment: @egreg: Never say never. An obvious example of using both in the same document is a document explaining the difference between `\phi` and `\varphi`.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Try the following:

```
$\phi\varphi$
\let\temp\phi
\let\phi\varphi
\let\varphi\temp
$\phi\varphi$
```

Comment: Okay, so my issue before is that I was using \renewcommand instead of \let. Could you elaborate on the differences between the two commands?

Comment: `\let\a\b` makes \a have the definition that `\b` has so `\let\a\a` is a no-op  `\newcommand\a{\b}` makes a expand to \b so `\newcommand\a{\a}` makes a expand to itself and loop forever

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Okay so it's essentially hard linking versus symbolic linking. Which is what I suspected the issue was. Thanks.

Answer (score 40):

The usual way to exchange two values is to use a temporary command name to store one of them while swapping, but if, for no particular reason, you want to avoid the extra command name then:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

$\phi\varphi$


\expandafter\mathchardef\expandafter\varphi\number\expandafter\phi\expandafter\relax
\expandafter\mathchardef\expandafter\phi\number\varphi

$\phi\varphi$


\end{document}
```

Comment: haha, saving up just that extra bit of namespace!

Comment: What the…?! Cool! `:-D`

Comment: I see, you are using the input stream as temporary storage.

Answer (score 17):

For non-complex macros, using an interim macro to swap definitions is sufficient. However, if the macros (say, `funcA` and `funcB`) takes optional arguments, you need to use a different approach via [`letltxmacro`](http://ctan.org/pkg/letltxmacro)'s macro `\LetLtxMacro{<new macro>}{<old macro>}`:

```
\usepackage{letltxmacro}% http://ctan.org/pkg/letltxmacro
%...
\LetLtxMacro{\temp}{\funcA}
\LetLtxMacro{\funcA}{\funcB}
\LetLtxMacro{\funcB}{\temp}
```

Comment: +1 for giving an answer with less `\expandafter`s but more use than mine.