# Multiple evaluation of a macro argument with side effects?

Tags: macros

In C, preprocessor macros can have unexpected effects because their arguments can be evaluated multiple times.  For example, the following code:

```c
#define MAX(a,b) ((a)>(b) ? (a) : (b))
int i = 5, j = MAX(i++, 0);
```

becomes:

```c
int i = 5, j = ((i++)>(0) ? (i++) : (0));
```

and the variable `i` will have the value 7—not 6 as expected—because the macro's arguments are repeated in the macro definition.

Does LaTeX have similar issues?  For example, what would happen in the following:

```
\newcommand{\foo}[1]{#1 #1}
\foo{\somethingwithsideeffects}
```

Would the side effects happen twice?  If so, how can that be avoided?  Can `\edef` be cleverly used to cause side effects to happen only once?  Or `\sbox` (assuming the argument is something you want boxed)?  Or maybe some way to automatically remove tokens that have side effects from `#1`?

Is this a problem in practice?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The side effect can occur in TeX as well. As far as I know there is no real way to avoid them. That is, if you produce something like you did in your example, there is no way to change `\foo` to accommodate that. Take the following example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\gdef\switch{1}
\def\temp{\ifnum\switch=1\def\switch{0}x\else\def\switch{1}y\fi}
\def\foo#1{#1 #1}
\foo\temp
\end{document}
```

This will produce `x y`, because first the `#1`s in foo are replaced by their replacement text (`\temp`) and then those are expanded one at a time. That means `\switch` is changed before the second `\temp` is expanded. In this simple example grouping would help. If we changed the definition of `\foo` to `\def\foo#1{{#1}{#1}}` then it would print `x x`. However, this stops working when we `\gdef` instead of `\def` `\switch` inside of `\temp`. The problem is, if we can't modify `\temp` then we can't really do anything about that in `\foo`. So if you pass a macro with side effects to a macro that uses that argument more than once, it can lead to problems.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  Can `\edef` or `\sbox` be used to eliminate the multiple side effects?  See my revised question.

Answer (score 3):

This is a common problem when dealing with float captions. For example, here's the definition of `\@makecaption` which is called by `\caption` (taken from [`article.cls`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/unpacked/article.cls)):

```
\long\def\@makecaption#1#2{%
  \vskip\abovecaptionskip
  \sbox\@tempboxa{#1: #2}%
  \ifdim \wd\@tempboxa >\hsize
    #1: #2\par
  \else
    \global \@minipagefalse
    \hb@xt@\hsize{\hfil\box\@tempboxa\hfil}%
  \fi
  \vskip\belowcaptionskip}
```

The caption is set inside a box `\@tempboxa`, after which its tested for horizontal width. If it fits, then the original box `\@tempboxa` is set, otherwise it is re-evaluated. The re-evaluation is performed to switch from centred (the default) to paragraph-style alignment of the caption. So, any `\label` or counter-related entries should be used with caution (especially if there's a contents for the floats created as well). Here's a small example:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcounter{myitem}
\newcommand{\mynewitem}{\addtocounter{myitem}{1}I-\themyitem}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[ht]
  \centering\rule{150pt}{\baselineskip}
  \caption{This is \mynewitem.}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}[ht]
  \centering\rule{150pt}{\baselineskip}
  \caption{This is \mynewitem\ together with a lengthy caption that stretches more than one line.}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Resolutions to these problems are sometimes provided by manual work-around (which may vary on a case-by-case basis), or perhaps a package. Most solutions are provided by going back to the source and trying to understand the root of the problem, which invariably provide hints to possible work-arounds.

On a side-note. An interesting example of TeX's capability to be different from a programming language is presenting in David's answer to [How do you swap the commands for two symbols?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/50365/5764), suggesting that it's not always necessary to use a intermediate variable.