# How to define in one Chapter two parts

Tags: chapters, parts

I was wondering where this is possible in LaTeX?

> Chapter 2
>
> Part 1
>
> Section 2.1.1
>
> Section 2.1.2
>
> Subsection 2.1.2.1
>
> Subsection 2.1.2.2
>
> Part 2
>
> Section 2.2.1
>
> Section 2.2.2
>
> Subsection 2.2.2.1
>
> Subsection 2.2.2.2

Comment: Why don't you just use the `\section`s normally?  They will all get the correct numbering as you want.  If not, why don't you simply use two `\chapters`?  Or even a third option, you can used `\part` where a `\chapter` can be nested and then another `\part` for a different one.

Comment: @kan I need to labelled parts, sections and sub sections the way I have mentioned

Comment: You seem to want an extra sectioning level between chapter and section. I, personally, would just us \section for the parts and \subsection for the next level, etc. An alternative is to make two chapters with the same title, except "(part 1}" added to the first and "(part 2)" to the second. Adding an official level between chapter and section would be problematic in chapters that didn't have parts. Sections would be numbered like 2.0.1, 2.0.2, etc.

Answer (score 3):

I’d simply [swap](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/50360/16595) parts and chapters here. So you use `\part` for your chapters and `\chapter` for your parts (of a chapter).

Swapping the headings “Part” and “Chapter” which are stored in `\partname` and `\chaptername` respectively can be done with

```
\begingroup
  \let\swap\partname
  \global\let\partname\chaptername
  \global\let\chaptername\swap
\endgroup
```

Then we simply need to set up the correct numbering scheme.

First, you want your chapters (LaTeX’ parts) to be arabic:

```
\renewcommand*{\thepart}{\arabic{part}}
```

We don’t need to change anything about the chapters (your parts).

Then we only need to setup `\thesection` so that they include the numbers from the parts and chapters (yours and LaTeX’).

---

We could also swap `\chapter` and `\part` but this won’t work successfully because `\chapter` (and maybe `\part`, too) is used in other macros (like `\tableofcontents`) to create a heading.

It is however possible to use `\Chapter` and `\Part`:

```
\let\Chapter\part
\let\Part\chapter
```

---

To avoid confusion I named the chapters and parts in German so we can properly observe the swap of `\chaptername` and `\partname`.

### Code

```
\documentclass{book}
\begingroup
  \let\swap\partname
  \global\let\partname\chaptername
  \global\let\chaptername\swap
\endgroup
\renewcommand*{\thepart}{\arabic{part}}
\renewcommand*{\thesection}{\thepart.\thechapter.\arabic{section}}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\stepcounter{part}% let's start with chapter 2 as in your example

\part{Kapitel 2}
\chapter{Teil 1}
\section{Section 2.1.1}
\section{Section 2.1.2}
\subsection{Subsection 2.1.2.1}
\subsection{Subsection 2.1.2.2}
\chapter{Teil 2}
\section{Section 2.2.1}
\section{Section 2.2.2}
\subsection{Subsection 2.2.2.1}
\subsection{Subsection 2.2.2.2}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image][image]

Comment: And such an answer cries  for Section "Tricky Answers" in the TeX - LaTeX Weekly Newsletter. :-)

Answer (score 2):

You could [demote some sectional units](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/61766/5764) and insert `\part` to replace `\section`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{book}

\let\part\section% Demote \part
\let\section\subsection% Demote \section
\let\subsection\subsubsection% Demote \subsection
\let\subsubsection\paragraph% Demote \subsubsection
\let\paragraph\subparagraph% Demote \paragraph
%\let\subparagraph\relax%

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{First chapter}
\part{First part}
\section{First section}
\section{Second section}
\subsection{First subsection}
\subsection{Second subsection}
\part{Second part}
\section{First section}
\section{Second section}
\subsection{First subsection}
\subsection{Second subsection}

\chapter{Second chapter}
\part{First part}
\section{First section}
\section{Second section}
\subsection{First subsection}
\subsection{Second subsection}
\part{Second part}
\section{First section}
\section{Second section}
\subsection{First subsection}
\subsection{Second subsection}

\end{document}
```

Formatting of the respective components in terms of their display/run-in setting can be achieved via other packages (like [`secsty`](http://ctan.org/pkg/secsty) or [`titlesec`](http://ctan.org/pkg/titlesec), for example).