# Swap many pair of command names in a row

Tags: macros, loops, scoping, primitives, alias

I've learnt from [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/50362/72679) how to swap two commands using the `let` primitive:

```
\let\temp\first
\let\first\second
\let\second\temp
\let\temp\undefined
```

Now, in order not to flood my preamble with this pattern, and to ease maintenance of my document, I wish to loop over this to perform all my swaps at once, with something like:

```
\foreach \lhs/\rhs in {%
    phi/varphi,%    easier to..
    sim/thicksim,%  .. tweak and maintain ..
    % ...           .. with a long list of swaps
    } {%
       % .. what to input here?
       % \expandafter\let\csname\lhs\endcsname\csname\rhs\endcsname 
       % does not work, because \let seems confined inside the loop scope
    }
```

How do I perform all my swaps in a row like this?
Why is there not an `\xlet` like there is a `\xdef`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works by parsing a comma separated list of `\first/\second` macros using `listofitems`.  For the particular example, `\swap{\phi/\varphi,\alpha/\beta}`, this puts `\phi` into `\swaplist[1,1]` (after expanding twice the latter macro), `\varphi` into `\swaplist[1,2]`, `\alpha`  into `\swaplist[2,1]` and `\beta` into `\swaplist[2,2]`.

Now all that is required is a loop through the first index (performed with `\foreachitem`) to do what the OP showed at the top...a series of `\global\let`s.  The particulars are a game of expansion, so that the `\swaplist` macros are twice expanded at the time of the `\let.`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listofitems}
\def\swapA{\let\temp}
\newcommand\swap[1]{%
  \setsepchar[-]{,-/}%
  \readlist*\swaplist{#1}%
  \foreachitem\x\in\swaplist{%
    \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\swapA\swaplist[\xcnt,1]%
    \edef\swapB{\noexpand\global\noexpand\let\swaplist[\xcnt,1]}%
    \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\swapB\swaplist[\xcnt,2]%
    \edef\swapC{\noexpand\global\noexpand\let\swaplist[\xcnt,2]}%
    \expandafter\swapC\temp%
  }%
}
\begin{document}
\swap{\phi/\varphi,\alpha/\beta}
\noindent phi: $\phi$\\
 varphi: $\varphi$\\
 alpha: $\alpha$\\
 beta: $\beta$
\end{document}
```

[image]

If the alternate syntax is desired, that omits the backslashes, `\swap{phi/varphi,alpha/beta}`, then this would suffice, to accomplish the same task.  Double expansion is no longer needed, since `\csname` will fully expand its `\swaplist` argument.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listofitems}
\def\swapA{\let\temp}
\newcommand\swap[1]{%
  \setsepchar[-]{,-/}%
  \readlist*\swaplist{#1}%
  \foreachitem\x\in\swaplist{%
    \expandafter\swapA\csname\swaplist[\xcnt,1]\endcsname%
    \edef\swapB{\noexpand\global\noexpand\let\csname\swaplist[\xcnt,1]\endcsname}%
    \expandafter\swapB\csname\swaplist[\xcnt,2]\endcsname%
    \edef\swapC{\noexpand\global\noexpand\let\csname\swaplist[\xcnt,2]\endcsname}%
    \expandafter\swapC\temp%
  }%
}
\begin{document}
\swap{phi/varphi,alpha/beta}
\noindent phi: $\phi$\\
 varphi: $\varphi$\\
 alpha: $\alpha$\\
 beta: $\beta$
\end{document}
```

Comment: Wow. This seems to work indeed Ô.Ô What's the idea? Is the `\foreach` option a dead-end, and why?

Comment: @iago-lito I added some commentary.

Comment: Well, cheers :) I'll have a look into this `listofitems` package, which seems quite powerful. Anyway, it looks like LaTeX remains quite hard to read and write for humans, right? XD

Comment: @iago-lito I have added an alternate version, if you prefer the syntax without backslashes, `\swap{phi/varphi,alpha/beta}`

Comment: I don't mind. As long as it is easy to read and maintain :) But thanks!

Comment: @iago-lito The `listofitems` package is extremely powerful and handy for dissecting complex lists.  Documentation here: https://ctan.org/pkg/listofitems, and also search for `listofitems` on this tex.stackexchange website for ways it can be used.