Accessing an overridden Greek letter
Some colleagues have typed (and they somehow would like to keep it) in the preamble:
\def\epsilon{\varepsilon}

Can I access the ordinary \epsilon?
\documentclass{article}

\def\eps{\epsilon}
\def\epsilon{\varepsilon}

\begin{document}
 $\eps, \epsilon$
\end{document}


\def\epsilon\varepsilon is a syntax error they presumably do not have that, and have as you wrote in your later example \def\epsilon{\varepsilon}

https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/50360/how-do-you-swap-the-commands-for-two-symbols may be useful (you can just swap the definition of \epsilon and \varepsilon).

Fixed, thanks both.

You need to make a copy of the original definition. The low-level TeX primitive for it is \let, but nowadays the LaTeX kernel provides \NewCommandCopy
\documentclass{article}

\NewCommandCopy{\eps}{\epsilon}
\renewcommand*{\epsilon}{\varepsilon}

\begin{document}
$\eps, \epsilon$
\end{document}


